# Calculating Point Nemo

Tags: geographics

I am referring to Point Nemo which is the point farthest from any emerged land mass. Some relevant information can be found on [this](https://escales.ponant.com/en/point-nemo/) page.

I am not sure about -ve signs or whether it is the exact location, but using Google:

```
pointNemo = GeoPosition[{-48.52, -123.23}] 

GeoGraphics[{pointNemo
  , GeoMarker[{pointNemo}]
  , GeoDisk[pointNemo, Quantity[2700, "Kilometers"]]
  }
 , GeoRange -> Quantity[3500, "Kilometers"]
 , GeoProjection -> "Orthographic"
 ]
```

---

[image]

---

**Question(s)**

1. Using the `Geo*` functions in Mathematica, how can the farthest point from any land mass be calculated?
2. What is the closest land mass to Point Nemo?
3. How do I put a label/callout at both these locations?

I am thinking, "why not move this point upwards, since there seems to be plenty of ocean there"?

Comment: A related community [post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/905972).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Wolfram does not include all "emerged land" in its data base so its data cannot be used to calculate Point Nemo. See [`Motu Nui`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motu_Nui)

```
motunui = GeoPosition[{-27.12, -109.27`}];

pointNemo = GeoPosition[{-48.52, -123.23}];

GeoGraphics[{GeoMarker[{pointNemo, motunui}], 
  GeoDisk[pointNemo, Quantity[2700, "Kilometers"]]},
 GeoRange -> "World",
 GeoProjection -> {"Orthographic", "Centering" -> pointNemo},
 GeoGridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: How about `Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"IslaDePascua", "Valparaiso", 
  "Chile"}]` and `Entity["Country", "PitcairnIslands"]`?

Comment: @Syed - see https://www.lukatela.com/pointNemoRevisited/index.html